# List box showing out of range, even when it contains more elements than the index on which it is throwing error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, listbox

I am just trying to move items of one listbox to another. 
Even when list box contains elements , I am getting index out of range error.
Below is my code:

```
   While lstAccounts.Items.Count <> 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstAccounts.Items.Count-1
            lstSelectedAccounts.Items.Add(lstAccounts.Items(i))
            lstAccounts.Items.Remove(lstAccounts.Items(i))
        Next
    End While
```

Initially, lstAccounts contains 5 elements. It works fine inside for loop upto first three elements. But throwing error when `i=3`. But, why so! lstAccounts.Items(3) should return value as it consists of 5 elements initially.
Am I doing something stupid here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the lstAccounts items collection you need to count from 0 to Items.Count **-1**

Also, you can't remove items from a list when iterating over it - I think that why its failing. Try removing the items after adding to SelectedAccounts - outside the For loop.

For example:

```
            Dim itemsToRemove As New Generic.List(Of ListItem)
            For Each li As ListItem In lstAccounts.Items                    
                    lstSelectedAccounts.Items.Add(li)
                    itemsToRemove.Add(li)                    
            Next
            For Each li As ListItem In itemsToRemove
                lstAccounts.Items.Remove(li)
            Next
```

Comment: I was doing same, showing same error. Just debugged and kept 1 for checking it

Comment: I already did exactly same.Seems you beat me to writing it here. But I still ponder why previous code didn't work as it should have exited for loop instead of out of range error!

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is inside loop you are removing item from `lstAccounts` and you are give loop limit as **lstAccounts's count**

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstAccounts.Items.Count-1
            lstSelectedAccounts.Items.Add(lstAccounts.Items(i))
            lstAccounts.Items.Remove(lstAccounts.Items(i))
```

Your loop will loop 4 times

and when ever `i=0` means first loop you are removing 1 element from lstAccounts
like

```
 lstAccounts.Items.Remove(lstAccounts.Items(i))
```

so when again comes to loop the count of `lstAccounts`  will be 1 less than the old one means first time the count will be 5 and now it will be 4, and like wise it happens in each looping progress, and when i=3 your total count of `lstAccounts`  will be less than 3 and it will show out of range exception

Comment: Yeah, in this scenerio, when i=3 and count will be 3, it will be 3<2, should it not exit for loop there and continue with next while loop iteration and I am resetting count and i to 0 again.